# how to call a function from class to another class c++

Tags: c++, function, class, if-statement

I want to know how to call a function from a class which contains "If" "Else" condition to another class? In the following code which I've tried cout<<"fail"<<'\n'; works for the answer2 not for the answer3. How is it possible??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Addjob 
{   

    public:
        // class constructor
        Addjob();
        // class destructor
        ~Addjob();

    string a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7;
    string answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,answer5,answer6,answer7;



       public:
       void addjobdt()
         {
             cout<<a1<<endl; // Client's Name
             getline(cin,answer1);
             cin.ignore();
             cout<<'\n';

             cout<<a2<<endl; // Client's Add
             getline(cin,answer2);
             cin.ignore();
             cout<<'\n';


             cout<<a3<<endl; // ID number
             getline(cin,answer3);
             cin.ignore();
             if (answer3.length() < 4)
               {
                     cout<<"fail"<<'\n';           
                                }


         }
```

Comment: Declare the object of other class and call the required function...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
getline(cin, answer);
cin.ignore();
```

use:

```
cin >> answer;
```